# How to sum each column and print column name and column sum using awk?

Tags: text-processing, awk, arithmetic, statistics

I have a file with a table of numbers; the first line is a header line.
I want to sum each column and print out sum and column name for each column using awk.

How can I do it?

Comment: This question needs example input and output. It's unclear otherwise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that every line has the same number of fields (columns):

```
awk '
    NR==1   { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) header[i]=$i; next; }
            { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) total[i] += $i; }
    END     { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print header[i] "=" total[i]+0 }
    '
```

Sample input:

```
red green blue
1 2 4
8 16 32
64 128 256
```

Corresponding output:

```
red=73
green=146
blue=292
```

Comment: One small improvement: on line 1 set `n=NF` then, everywhere, loop until `i<=n` -- that will cover the case where there are too many headers, and the output will include `extra_header=0`

Comment: I was considering various approaches to handling badly formed input; capturing the number of headers was one of them.  But I’m not 100% sure that I understand your comment.   ISTM that setting `n=NF` when `NR==1` is mostly good for guarding against the last line of input having too *few* fields.  And, if I take your suggestion, and the input has 42 headers, then my script will iterate over 42 fields even on lines that don’t have that many.  I believe that capturing the *maximum* `NF` would be more robust.

Comment: IMO you want a count for each header, so NF on line 1 will drive the counting. I don't know what we would want to output for lines with too many fields.