# Add a list of values of column A and B separated by space and show the summation result

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a file called `fold.txt`. It has two values in each lines separated by a space. If I say that first value represent column A and second value after space is column B then how can I add all the values of column A and all the values of column B and show the summation of each column individually?

I am expecting something like this:

```
$ cat fold.txt
100 500
200 300
700 100
```

Output:

```
Total count Column A = 1000
Total count column B = 900
```

Comment: Closely related: [How to sum each column and print column name and column sum using awk?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/520250/how-to-sum-each-column-and-print-column-name-and-column-sum-using-awk)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk '{ sum_A +=$1; sum_B+=$2; };
END{ print "Total count Column A = " sum_A +0;
     print "Total count column B = " sum_B +0;
}' infile
```

in [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) language which is a tool for text-processing purposes, `$1` represent first column's value, `$2` represent second column's value, `$3` for third and so on and one special one `NF` is represent the last column Id and accordingly `$NF` is the last column's value (so you can replace `$2` above with `$NF` too; and yes you catch it when `NF` is the last column Id, so value of the variable tells you how many columns do you have (its value update for each line awk is read form the input) ).

To handle the edge case where the input file is empty and still get numeric output we add 0 to the result forcing `awk` to output numeric result.

columns (or fields) in `awk` distinguished by the `FS` variable (**F**eild **S**eparator) which default is use Space/Tabs. if you want columns split on different character, you can redefine it with the `-F` option for `awk` like in:

```
awk -F'<character-here>' '...' infile
```

or within `BEGIN{...}` block like with `FS`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS="<character-here>"; }; { ... }' infile
```

for example for a input file like below (now it's comma instead of space):

```
100,500
200,300
700,100
```

you can write your `awk` code as following:

```
awk -F',' '{ sum_A +=$1; sum_B+=$2; };
END{ print "Total count Column A = " sum_A +0;
     print "Total count column B = " sum_B +0;
}' infile
```

Or within `BEGIN` block:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=","; }; { sum_A +=$1; sum_B+=$2; };
END{ print "Total count Column A = " sum_A +0;
     print "Total count column B = " sum_B +0;
}' infile
```

---

Going a little bit complex and to sum all *N* columns of your input file on the following sample:

```
100,500,140,400
200,300,640,200
700,100,400,130
```

---

So we talked about `NF` in first paragraph (NF value is telling you how many columns do you have (update per each line)):

```
awk -F',' '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) sum[i]+=$i; };
END{ for (colId in sum) { 
         printf ("Total count Column: %d= %d\n", colId, sum[colId] );
     };
}' infile
```

the only new things here is we used `awk` array to address the same column Id taking from the value of `i` and add their values `$i` into that array (index/keys of this array is column Ids); then at the `END{...}` block we loop over our array on the keys it's seen then print the column Id first then sum of those next to it, you will see output like below:

```
Total count Column: 1= 1000
Total count Column: 2= 900
Total count Column: 3= 1180
Total count Column: 4= 730
```

Comment: Thank you very much Afshin for elaborating it. This is something that I was looking for. I am familiar with awk and use it in my day to day shell scripting but I have never done solving/calculating math with it. Will deep dive into this more.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good job for dc.

dc read first the data from fold.txt and after the code from sum_col_dc.

Use it like that : dc fold.txt sum_col_dc

```
cat sum_col_dc  

[lB+sBlA+sAz0<C]sC[lGLElDnnnp]sH[Total count Column ]sD[B]sE[A]SE[ = ]sGlCxlAlHxlBlHx
```

With a little more details:

```
[lB+sBlA+sAz0<C]sC  
[lGLElDnnnp]sH  
[Total count Column ]sD  
[B]sE  
[A]SE  
[ = ]sG  
lCx  
lA  
lHx  
lB  
lHx
```

Enjoy dc
More explain on demand.